# How can encode url of uiwebview into exact url from that url in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, nsstring

I am having one issue related extracting of string in iOS. I am getting NSURL value from WebView http://m.youtube.com/index?&desktop_uri=%2F, however i need to extract only http://m.youtube.com, i have tried many steps, however it didn't work, please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looking at the `NSURL` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I can see that an `NSURL` object has various properties that give you what you want:

```
http://m.youtube.com
|  A  |      B     |

A: Scheme
B: Host
```

So I think all you need to do is:

```
NSURL *url = ...;
NSString *scheme = url.scheme;
NSString *host = url.host;
NSLog(@"%@%@", scheme, host);
```

Job done.  NEXT!